# How do I define a \ifcommand only if it is not already defined?

Tags: conditionals

To deal with a mess of compilation alternatives with multiple files, I use some `\ifSomething` switches. But I stumble when I need to check if a switch is defined, and define it if it is not. Minimal example:

```
% This may or may not be present:
\newif\ifSomething
\Somethingfalse

% Later, (usually) in a different file:
\ifdefined \ifSomething 
\else
    \newif\ifSomething 
    \Somethingtrue
\fi

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Everything ok?
\end{document}
```

I believe I understand the problem: Because `\ifSomething` is already defined, its appearance in the`\else` clause is interpreted as starting a conditional-- the fact that it's the argument of `\newif` notwithstanding. I even remember reading about this in the TeXbook... but how *should* I do this?

Comment: `\expandafter\ifx\csname ifSomething\endcsname\relax
\newif\ifSomething 
\Somethingtrue
\fi`  should work too

Comment: @Christian, I think the use after `\ifdefined` does not need protecting, just the one after `\newif`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Protecting??? I don't understand what you mean. I just compare whether `\ifSomething` is defined with `\ifx` or is `\relax`

Comment: I was using the term loosely, sorry. I meant with `\csname`... not with `\protect`.

Comment: `\expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\relax` tests whether `\foo` is defined or is equal to `\relax`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ifSomething}{%
  \newif\ifSomething
  \Somethingtrue
}{}
\makeatother
```

`\@ifundefined` generates the macro name from the argument string and tests, whether the command is undefined (or `\relax`). This removes the `\if...` token from the test. Also the branching is syntactically realized via arguments and not by `\if...\else...\fi`. Therefore an defined or undefined `\ifSomething` does not cause trouble for `\@ifundefined`.

However, there is a case, where `\ifSomething` after `\newif` in the argument can cause trouble, when the whole construct is inside a `\if`/`\else` branch. Then the trick is `\csname`:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ifSomething}{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname ifSomething\endcsname
  \Somethingtrue
}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I can also just use the `\csname` approach with a TeX-style if: `\ifdefined\ifSomething \else \expandafter\newif\csname ifSomething\endcsname \fi`. Is this going to cause problems in some uses?

Comment: @alexis The number if `\if...` tokens do not match with one `\else` and `\fi`. Thus this causes trouble, when the whole construct is inside another `\if...` construct. A solution would be e-TeX's `\ifcsname`: `\ifcsname ifSomething\endcsname...\else...\fi`.

Comment: That rings a bell now (from the TeXbook), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `etoolbox` package has `\providebool`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifSomething

\providebool{Something}
\providebool{SomethingElse}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\Somethingtrue}

\texttt{\meaning\SomethingElsetrue}

\end{document}
```

[image]